# Question disappearing upon page refresh

Tags: bug, navigation

I would like to point out the bug which I have started to encounter recently:

When a new question is asked, a notification is displayed as: "one new question is to this activity" and when I click it it shows the problem, and every thing is going good, but after clicking the notification, if I refresh the page, the question is gone!!

After refreshing for several times, or after some time, it shows again.
Please solve this problem ASAP.

Comment: I tagged this [tag:new-nav] since it reads like a bug with the new navigation. If it isn't, please remove that tag again.

Comment: @Pat nono, it has happened to any nav.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. @nicael

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is annoying, I agree. But the reason is caching. The /questions page, like many others, is server-side cached and it takes a few minutes for it to get updated.

The live updates, at least on the questions/answers "new activity" are not cached (because their primary purpose is it be live). Hence the inconsistency.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is browser caching, not server caching. The notification and the question are delivered by AJAX and inserted dynamically by your browser into the page it displays.

When you refresh, the browser gets the page again: but it displays its cached version, it doesn't get the page afresh from the server. If you force-refresh the page (usually shift-ctrl-R or some such keystroke), the browser will get the current version of the page from the server, and that will be complete.

The reason that refreshing more than once works is that the browser cache has expired by that point, so the page is fetched from the server.

Comment: No, the *primary* problem is the server caching, not the browser. The fix won't help.

Comment: Well, I've never found this to fail, and Firebug corroborates it. Perhaps both browser and server caching are involved.